# Is BQ billing different when using BigQuery pagination and when using LIMIT and OFFSET?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-billing

I have a BQ query which returns around 25K records as of now and I want to apply pagination to it to fetch it in chunks of 1000.

Based on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/paging-results) I can add BQ pagination by setting the `maxResults` property and use pageToken to get the next set of results.

I know that I add my own logic and use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` but as per the documentation the billing will be for all the rows and not only the number of rows that are fetched

> Applying a LIMIT clause to a SELECT * query does not affect the amount
> of data read. You are billed for reading all bytes in the entire
> table, and the query counts against your free tier quota.

But I can't seem to find any documentation which gives me a clear idea whether using `maxResults` property will actually reduce the amount of data that I'm billed for.

Can anyone please advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant - Can you please help?